# How to efficiently iterate through a pandas dataframe and calculate a value of a subset of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say there is a DataFrame with the following values:

1. var1 = [values between 1 and 100]
2. var2 = [values between 1 and 100]
3. var3 = [values between 1 and 100]
4. flag = [flag (0 or 1) indicating an outcome of an event]

I want to create a list that has the sum of the flag column (number of events) when var1, var2, and var3 are above the given values. I then want to do this for every combination of var1, var2, and var3.

Here is some example code of doing this with nested for loops, but I am looking for a quicker way to accomplish it. Thanks!

```
sum_list = []

for i in range(1,100,1):
    for j in range(1,100,1):
        for k in range(1,100,1):

            df_temp = df[(df['var1'] >= i) & (df['var2'] >= j) & (df['var3'] >= k)]

            sum_list.append(df_temp['total'].sum())
```

Comment: Are you intending to have 1 million entries in sum_list when the loops are complete?

Comment: Please show what your dataframe and what the expected output column looks like.

Comment: Yes, I am intending to have 1 million entries in sum_list at the end.